# Sizzle text equals

Tags: sizzle

With the Sizzle selector engine, is it possible to find buttons with the *exact* text?

For example, `button:contains('Remove Document')` will match any buttons that have the text "Remove Document" but I need it to *not* match buttons that say "Don't Remove Document". Is there a selector that will match the whole text, start to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `:contains` inside `:not` to not match something :

```
$("button:not(:contains(Don't Remove Document))")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8guAm/)

Comment: True, but that implies advocating an inordinately complex solution, if there are a number of buttons that contain, but are not limited to, the desired text.

Comment: @DavidThomas: We could always do `button:contains(Remove Document):not(:contains(Don't))` http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/8guAm/1/ Which works for my scenario, but it's not as pretty as, say, `button[@text='Remove Document']`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `filter` there :

```
$("button").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim()==='Remove Document';
});
```

If you really want to have it in one sizzle selector string, starting from adeneo's answer and completing it, you may use

```
button:contains("Remove Document"):not(:contains("Don"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I only put the jQuery tag there in case people weren't familiar with Sizzle. I'm not using jQuery. I need a single selector string.

Comment: Using a single selector string here is doable (see adeneo's answer) but you might not be using the right tool, this will be uselessly heavy.

Comment: Darn, I was gonna say you could functionify this for more general use. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g3L3d/